# JavaFX Change Gradient Background Opacity without Affecting Children

Tags: java, css, javafx, colors

I'm trying to set the CSS background color for a pane in my program to a linear gradient with a 0.5 opacity without changing the opacity of the children nodes also.

This is my CSS currently.

```
pane {
    -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient(to right, #ffafbd, #ffc3a0);
    -fx-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I'm stumbled across this issue often with regular colored backgrounds in CSS and I know that the alpha channel value can be adjusted in that case.
Ex:

```
pane {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Are there any similar solutions that I can apply to a background that's not simply a solid color?

Comment: simply use rgba color inside the gradient .. and a gradient isn't a color but image so use `background` and not `background-color`

Comment: @TemaniAfif  oh wow that was easy *facepalm* thank you very much if you want to answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

I`m using this css gradient on pane on top of image to mask half of the image

```
.pane {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 50% to 100% 50%, rgba(244,244,244,1), rgba(244,244,244,0));
}
```

result:

[image]